# Does bit (information) have a plural

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, measuring-units

I'm wondering if the word "bit" in its information theory / computer science sense actually has a plural.

If "bit" is used like a unit of measurement, then it should mostly be used in its singular forms. E.g. "20 bit of data is received" or "The capacity of this medium is 200 bit". However, this would make the use of "bit" as a noun for a small piece of information difficult.

So for example, while reading publications, I've often encountered sentences like "The bits received by the radio are processed by a decoder".

Now some people say, that the latter use of "bit" is wrong. I'm wondering if that is actually the case and all those occurrences are actually false English that has gone mainstream.

Not being a native speaker myself, I could not find a definitive conclusion. Sources like the Oxford English Dictionary (online) don't seem to mention a plural form for "bit". But it seems so common to talk about "bits" that I wanted to make sure.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow *If "bit" is used like a unit of measurement, then it should mostly be used in its singular forms.* What units of measure behave this way? Consider one meter vs. twenty meters, one gram vs. twenty grams, one liter vs. twenty liters.

Comment: @Joel: My guess is that as a non-native speaker, OP is confusing usages like *"This is a twenty **litre** bottle"* with *"This bottle holds twenty **litres**"*. As such, I think this question is General Reference.

Comment: A few units of measurement aren't pluralized: e.g. I think you might say "seventeen bar" when referring to pressure. [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_(unit)) "The word "bar" is constant, regardless singular or plural." I don't know why that is, but it's the exception: most units of measurement (inches, degrees, metres, amps, etc.) are said with a plural, including "bits".

Comment: @Joel Anair. E.g. ASCII encodes 128 characters into 7-bit binary integers.  I wouldn't touch that with a six-foot pole.

Comment: No one seems to have mentioned that _bit_ is an abbreviation of _Binary digIT_ and so any plural form of _binary digit_ also applies to _bit_, hence _bits_ is perfectly legitimate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As any other unit of measurement, **bit** also has its plural form - **bits**.

> 20 bits of data is received.
>
> The capacity of this medium is 200 bits.

Using the singular form in both sentences would be wrong. If you use just the single-digit version - **b**, you do not need to put the `s` at the end: **200b**.

Maybe in some contexts, where each of the separate bits is not so important as the whole chunk of data itself, the singular form can still be used, but I cannot think of any good example right now.

Comment: You can speak about a 32-bit word, but that's still a word that contains 32 bits.

Comment: @keshlam, exactly, in the same way as a "*12 foot pole*" (not *12 feet pole* and definitely *12 foots pole*).

Comment: @Dan Bron, do you think my usage of comma in the first sentence is correct? I just noticed it and I think it should not be there, but I am not sure.

Comment: Arsen, that comma works for me (occurs where there would be a natural pause if the sentence were spoken aloud). I'm not a fan of the em dash (hypen), but that's just a typographical pet peeve of mine.

Comment: @Dan Bron: I use the em-dash all the time—I love it. :-)

Comment: I downvoted because "20 bits of data is received" should be "are received".

Comment: @TRomano, `data is received` no matter if it consists of 1 bit or 20 bits.

Comment: @Arsen Y.M.: In your sentence, "bits", not "data", is the noun with which the verb must agree.  20 bottles of ink were purchased. FWIW, *data* is technically the plural of *datum*, though it has come to treated (often, not always) as a singular noun.

Comment: Typo, too late to fix: come to be treated

Comment: @TRomano, agree, `are` is correct. Now I wonder if `is` is incorrect. I still think this is a case where it is acceptable, since we talk about a chunk of data, which consists of 20 bits, and hardly each bit represents any meaningful entity itself.

Answer (score 3):

*Bit* when used as a unit of measurement is singular.

> ASCII encodes 128 characters into 7-bit binary integers.

Otherwise it works like a normal noun, with singular and plural.

> The client received 2,146, 567 bits of data from the server. About two million bits were received.
>
> Here we flip the leading bit to zero.

Comment: It has nothing to do with "when used as a unit of measurement", but "when used as a pre-nominal modifier". Compare: *a cracker box* does not contain a single cracker, *a two-person vehicle* does not seat a single person... It is a rule in English that nouns that modify other nouns should be singular.

Comment: I follow your statement of the pre-nominal rule, but not your example. What about my answer makes you believe I would think a two-person vehicle  seated one person? I said "bit" would be singular in "7-bit integers". Integers there is plural.

Comment: "bit" is not singular because it is a unit of measurement. It is a unit of measurement in "2,146, 567 bits of data" as well. Your examples are correct, but your explanation is not. My examples just illustrate the pre-nominal modifier rule, since without it, one would expect "a two-people vehicle" and "a crackers box".

Comment: Does the pre-nominal rule apply also when the noun is only implied, by virtue of an antecedent? E.g. What size ladders do you carry? We have 6-foot, 12-foot, 16-foot, and 24-foot.  ASCII encoding is 7-bit.

Comment: None of those sound quite right to me, but someone might disagree. I'd say "...24-foot *ones*", "... is a 7-bit *encoding*". But I can't quote an authority.